# when i switched on internet as a result data didn't sysnc

Tags: android, synchronization, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

i've made a form app that send data to my mysql server.

**how the app work :**

when the app doesn't have internet..the user enters the data and is submitted if I have internet but if i don't have internet acces and the user still sends data when the internet is activated again all the data saved is transmited to my mysql server

**Questions**

at the moment everything works , when there is internet connection it syncs without any trouble. 
for test purpose i switched off internet and then i added some data
but when i switched on internet as a result it didnt sysnc

i found several things but i am at beginners level. i don't find any samples.

i well share with you all my code , to understand my problem

**MainActivity.java**

```
    package com.example.hp.myapplication6;

    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.EditText;
   import android.widget.ListView;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;

    import com.android.volley.Request;
    import com.android.volley.Response;
    import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
{

    /*
   * this is the url to our webservice
   * make sure you are using the ip instead of localhost
   * it will not work if you are using localhost
   * */
    public static final String URL_SAVE_NAME = "http://192.168.1.100/SqliteSync/saveName.php";

    //database helper object
    private DatabaseHelper db;


    //View objects
    private Button buttonSave;
    private EditText editTextName;
    private ListView listViewNames;
    private EditText editTextPrenom;
    private EditText editTextAdess;

    //List to store all the names
    private List<Name> names;

    //1 means data is synced and 0 means data is not synced
    public static final int NAME_SYNCED_WITH_SERVER = 1;
    public static final int NAME_NOT_SYNCED_WITH_SERVER = 0;


    //a broadcast to know weather the data is synced or not
    public static final String DATA_SAVED_BROADCAST = "net.simplifiedcoding.datasaved";

    //Broadcast receiver to know the sync status
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;

    //adapterobject for list view
    private NameAdapter nameAdapter;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        registerReceiver(new NetworkStateChecker(), new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));

        //initializing views and objects
        db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        names = new ArrayList<>();

        buttonSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);
        editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        listViewNames = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewNames);
        editTextPrenom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPrenom);
        editTextAdess = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.geoadress);

        //adding click listener to button
        buttonSave.setOnClickListener(this);

        //calling the method to load all the stored names
        loadNames();

        //the broadcast receiver to update sync status
        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                //loading the names again
                loadNames();
            }
        };

        //registering the broadcast receiver to update sync status
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(DATA_SAVED_BROADCAST));
    }


    /*
* this method will
* load the names from the database
* with updated sync status
* */
    private void loadNames() {
        names.clear();
        Cursor cursor = db.getNames();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Name name = new Name(
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_PRENOM)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ADRESS)),
                        cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_STATUS))
                );
                names.add(name);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        nameAdapter = new NameAdapter(this, R.layout.names, names);
        listViewNames.setAdapter(nameAdapter);
    }

    /*
* this method will simply refresh the list
* */
    private void refreshList()
    {
        nameAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    /*
* this method is saving the name to ther server
* */
    private void saveNameToServer() {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Saving Name...");
        progressDialog.show();

        final String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
        final String prenom = editTextPrenom.getText().toString().trim();
        final String geoadress = editTextAdess.getText().toString().trim();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_SAVE_NAME,
                new Response.Listener<String>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                            if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {
                                //if there is a success
                                //storing the name to sqlite with status synced
                                saveNameToLocalStorage(name,prenom,geoadress, NAME_SYNCED_WITH_SERVER);
                            } else {
                                //if there is some error
                                //saving the name to sqlite with status unsynced
                                saveNameToLocalStorage(name,prenom,geoadress, NAME_NOT_SYNCED_WITH_SERVER);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        //on error storing the name to sqlite with status unsynced
                        saveNameToLocalStorage(name,prenom,geoadress, NAME_NOT_SYNCED_WITH_SERVER);
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("name", name);
                params.put("prenom", prenom);
                params.put("geoadress",geoadress );
                return params;
            }
        };

        VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }


    //saving the name to local storage
    private void saveNameToLocalStorage(String name,String prenom, String geoadress, int status) {
        editTextName.setText("");
        editTextPrenom.setText("");
        editTextAdess.setText("");
        db.addName(name,prenom,geoadress, status);
        Name n = new Name(name,prenom,geoadress, status);
        names.add(n);
        refreshList();
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        saveNameToServer();
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifist.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hp.myapplication6">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.example.hp.myapplication6.NetworkStateChecker">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**NetworkStateCheker.java**

```
package com.example.hp.myapplication6;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class NetworkStateChecker extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    //context and database helper object
    private Context context;
    private DatabaseHelper db;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        this.context = context;

        db = new DatabaseHelper(context);

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        //if there is a network
        if (activeNetwork != null) {
            //if connected to wifi or mobile data plan
            if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI || activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {

                //getting all the unsynced names
                Cursor cursor = db.getUnsyncedNames();
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        //calling the method to save the unsynced name to MySQL
                        saveName(
                                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ID)),
                                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME)),
                                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_PRENOM)),
                                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ADRESS))
                        );
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            }
        }

    }


    /*
* method taking two arguments
* name that is to be saved and id of the name from SQLite
* if the name is successfully sent
* we will update the status as synced in SQLite
* */
    private void saveName(final int id, final String name, final String prenom, final String geoadress) {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, MainActivity.URL_SAVE_NAME,
                new Response.Listener<String>(){
                    @Override

                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                            if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {
                                //updating the status in sqlite
                                db.updateNameStatus(id, MainActivity.NAME_SYNCED_WITH_SERVER);

                                //sending the broadcast to refresh the list
                                context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(MainActivity.DATA_SAVED_BROADCAST));
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("name", name);
                params.put("prenom", prenom);
                params.put("geoadress", geoadress);
                return params;
            }
        };

        VolleySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

**NameAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.hp.myapplication6;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class NameAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Name>
{

    //storing all the names in the list
    private List<Name> names;

    //context object
    private Context context;


    public NameAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<Name> names)
    {
        super(context, resource, names);

        this.context = context;
        this.names = names;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent)
    {
        //getting the layoutinflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        //getting listview itmes
        View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.names, null, true);
        TextView textViewName = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        ImageView imageViewStatus = (ImageView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.imageViewStatus);

        //getting the current name
        Name name = names.get(position);

        //setting the name to textview
        textViewName.setText(name.getName());

        //if the synced status is 0 displaying
        //queued icon
        //else displaying synced icon
        if (name.getStatus() == 0)
            imageViewStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stopwatch);
        else
            imageViewStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.success);

        return listViewItem;
    }


}
```

**Name.java**

```
package com.example.hp.myapplication6;


public class Name
{

    private String name;
    private String prenom;
    private String geoadress;
    private int status;


    public Name(String name,String prenom,String geoadress, int status) {
        this.name = name;
        this.prenom = prenom;
        this.geoadress = geoadress;
        this.status = status;
    }


    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public int getStatus()
    {
        return status;
    }


}
```

**VolleySingleton.java**

```
package com.example.hp.myapplication6;


import android.content.Context;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;


public class VolleySingleton
{
    private static VolleySingleton mInstance;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private static Context mCtx;



    private VolleySingleton(Context context) {
        mCtx = context;
        mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();

    }


    public static synchronized VolleySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new VolleySingleton(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
            // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }
}
```

**DataBaseHelper.java**

```
package com.example.hp.myapplication6;


import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    //Constants for Database name, table name, and column names
    public static final String DB_NAME = "NamesDB";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "contacts";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_PRENOM = "prenom";

    public static final String COLUMN_ADRESS = "geoadress";

    public static final String COLUMN_STATUS = "status";


    //database version
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_NAME + " VARCHAR, " + COLUMN_PRENOM + " VARCHAR, " + COLUMN_ADRESS + " VARCHAR, " + COLUMN_STATUS + " TINYINT);";
        db.execSQL(sql);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int OldVersion, int NewVersion)
    {
        String sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts";
        db.execSQL(sql);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /*
* This method is taking two arguments
* first one is the name that is to be saved
* second one is the status
* 0 means the name is synced with the server
* 1 means the name is not synced with the server
* */
    public boolean addName(String name,String prenom,String geoadress, int status) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(COLUMN_NAME, name);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_PRENOM, prenom);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_PRENOM, geoadress);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_STATUS, status);

        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        db.close();
        return true;
    }

    /*
* This method taking two arguments
* first one is the id of the name for which
* we have to update the sync status
* and the second one is the status that will be changed
* */
    public boolean updateNameStatus(int id, int status) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_STATUS, status);
        db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, COLUMN_ID + "=" + id, null);
        db.close();
        return true;
    }


    /*
* this method will give us all the name stored in sqlite
* */
    public Cursor getNames() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " + COLUMN_ID + " ASC;";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        return c;
    }


    /*
* this method is for getting all the unsynced name
* so that we can sync it with database
* */
    public Cursor getUnsyncedNames() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COLUMN_STATUS + " = 0;";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        return c;
    }


}
```

**activityMain.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.hp.myapplication6.MainActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:hint="Enter nom" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextPrenom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextName"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:hint="Enter prenom" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSave"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/geoadress"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Save" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewNames"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"></ListView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/geoadress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextPrenom"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="geoadress"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**names.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:text="Name"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:id="@+id/textViewName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:background="@drawable/success"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewStatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Also noone will do debugging for you.

Comment: i will post also the result of the debug

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski any help now ??

Comment: any information ???

Answer (score 0):

public boolean isOnline(Context mContext) {

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
//should check null because in airplane mode it will be null
return (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected());
```

}

Comment: So you call if(isOnline(context)){ //upload to online}

Comment: thank you for your answer , but i don't know how use it in my code ,  i am at beginners level , can you explain for me , or give me the right syntax who i can paste it  ,i also share with you the result of debuging thank you sir

Comment: any help sir ??